# odoo 13 upload video files via minio api of Python

Tags: python, odoo, minio, bytesio

I'm trying to develop a module to upload videos files via MinIO API of Python.

The file can be uploaded to MinIO, but it's cannot view via url like: http://localhost:9000/lms-videos/video/output.mp4. And also the file upload via MinIO should be 19.39Mb and the one uploaded via API turns out to be 25+MB, don't know what cause.....

Following is part of my code :

```
# minio client
@api.model
def _get_minio_client(self):
    host = '192.168.1.102:9000'
    access_key = 'minioadmin'
    secret_key = 'minioadmin'
    if not all((host, access_key, secret_key)):
        raise exceptions.UserError('Incorrect configuration of MinIO')
    return Minio(
    host,
    access_key = access_key,
    secret_key = secret_key,
    secure = False
    )
# upload
@api.model
def _store_file_write(self):
    client = self._get_minio_client()
    bin_data = self.datas_minio
    fname = "output_test"
    #client.put_object('lms-videos','videos/'+ fname + '.mp4',io.BytesIO(self.datas_minio), len(bin_data),'video/mp4')
    with io.BytesIO(self.datas_minio) as bin_data_io:
        client.put_object('lms-videos',
                          'videos/'+ fname + '.mp4',
                          bin_data_io,
                          len(bin_data),
                          'video/mp4')

@api.depends('document_id', 'slide_type', 'mime_type', 'external_url')
def _compute_embed_code(self):
    res = super(Slide, self)._compute_embed_code()
    for record in self:
        if record.slide_type == 'miniovideo':
            
            self._store_file_write()
            
            content_url = 'http://localhost:9000/lms-videos/videos/' + record.name + '.mp4'
            record.embed_code = '<video class="miniovideo" controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="' + content_url + '" type=MPEG-4/></video>'
        
@api.onchange('datas_minio')
def _on_change_datas(self):
    res = super(Slide, self)._on_change_datas()
    if self.datas_minio:
        #fname = self.datas_minio.decode("utf-8")
        #bin_data = self.datas_minio
        self._store_file_write()
        #self._get_minio_client().put_object('lms-videos', '/videos/'+ fname + '.mp4',io.BytesIO(bin_data), len(bin_data),'video/mp4')
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed by adding b64decode

```
@api.model
    def _store_file_write(self):
        client = self._get_minio_client()
        bin_data = base64.b64decode(self.datas_minio)
        fsize = len(bin_data)
        fname = "output_test"
       
        with io.BytesIO(bin_data) as bin_data_io:
            client.put_object('lms-videos',
                              #'videos/'+ fname + '.mp4',
                              'videos/output_test.mp4',
                              bin_data_io,
                              fsize,
                              'video/mp4')
```